# Displaying bitmap in ImageView from string

Tags: android, string, bitmap, imageview, uri

I want to display image that has been picked in previous activity from gallery to be displayed as bitmap for future so that I will be able to rotate it and things like that. I want to display bitmap as full picture with size determined by me (for example 128x128). I don't know how to get bitmap from string. When I want to do this, it says that non such file exists. Is there any other, better way?
Mine current code which works (displays properly), but it's still not bitmap, below. 
From MainActivity (first activity):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button browse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.browse);

    browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent picker = new Intent();
            picker.setType("image/*");
            picker.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            startActivityForResult(picker, SELECT_PICTURE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Uri selectedImage = null;

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            selectedImage = Uri.parse(data.getDataString());
            Intent pickerResult = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
            pickerResult.putExtra("IMAGE", selectedImage.toString());
            startActivity(pickerResult);
        }
```

And next activity (second one):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    if (getIntent().hasExtra("IMAGE")) {
        String pickedImage = getIntent().getStringExtra("IMAGE");
        imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(pickedImage));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for BitmapFactory.decodeFile:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29)

which will take the path (you'll probably need to strip file:// off of the Uri, or just take the path part of the Uri instead of toString'ing it in the string extra) and hand you back a bitmap.

Comment: How can I achieve it? Can you put any example?